# In Reactjs,is it possible to update the state of a component only for those items that satisfy a particular condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components which has their own individual states.The state contains a list of books for both the components.The parent component passes its state to the child component as props.The child component state which is also a list of books contains few books which are also present in the parent component's state.One can add a book from the child component to the parent component.Initially, the child component's books will have a property of shelf which will be set to "None".From the child component, a person can add a book to a shelf according to his wish.So,this book will be passed to the parent component which has the shelves listed.So,I want to check in the child component,if the book is already present in the shelf of the parent component.If it is, then I want to add the book's shelf in the child component(which is set to "None" initially) to the shelf name that it is in the parent component.So,I am able to do the check between both the components and get the list of books which are common to both.But now,I am not able to figure out how to update the state in the child component(change the shelf property from none to their respective shelf in parent component) only for the books that match the condition.

```
    let parent_books = this.props.books;     //Books state of the parent component

      //Mapping over the child component's books array
        this.state.books.map((book) => {
          const parent = parent_books.find(parent => parent.title === book.title );
          if(parent) {
            console.log(parent);     //Gives the list of books common to both the components
            book.shelf = parent.shelf;
            this.setState({ })      //Not able to figure out how to update the state which will
                                   // change the books shelf property only for the books which are common 
                                  //to both the component.The shelf still remains as "None" for all the books in child component 
          }
        })
```

Can anyone please guide me how to proceed?

Comment: Do you use any libraries like "redux" to maintain the application state or do you want to handle the state changes only between the child component and parent component. It is not very clear what you exactly want. If you could organize the question it will help to find you a solution

Comment: @ShashithDarshana No,I am not using redux as of now.I am only using the component state and passing it between the parent and child components which will be updated according to the condition.I will try to edit my question and elaborate it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are mapping, you need to return something.  Why not return the new book with the shelf property set?

```
if (parent && parent.shelf !== 'None') {
return Object.assign({}, book, {shelf: parent.shelf});
} else {
return book;
}
```

This would be the easiest way to accomplish what you want.  Also, please don't use set state inside the map; instead, set the state with the new books array after you have finished mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.The problem now is I am mapping over the child component's array and trying to update the state which satisfies the condition of having the book in both the components.Even when I assigned the shelf of the child component according to the parent component,the shelf of the child component is still "None".

Comment: I didn't see a return statement inside your map function.  So perhaps you are returning the origin child array instead of setting the property as you wish?  And you can update the state after mapping over the books array.  You really should not be making so many setState calls, as each will trigger a re-render of the component.

Comment: Okay.So can I assign the whole map function into  a constant and then assign that constant to the new state?And I need to return each book from the map function? Is this how the solution will work?

Comment: Correct.  You should be assigning mapped array to a variable regardless, as Array.map returns a new array; it does not modify the original array.

Comment: okay,just give me few mins.I will try it that way and let you know the outcome.Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This worked.Thank you so much.You saved my life. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a function to setState method which will return the new State. Inside the function we can check whatever condition you want to check to determine if you want update the state. If condition isn't met, simply return the oldstate. I guess that way your problem will be solved. Here is an example of the syntax -

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {counter: prevState.counter + props.step};
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Let me try the way you suggested.I will let you know how it goes.